# React calling action results infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following component. I want to run an action (this.props.selectCharacter) if condition is met. However, this results in an infinite loop currently maximum call stack exceeded

**components/board.js**

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.characters.map((character) => {
            // if the character is located correctly
            if(character.found === true) {
                // hide the overlay
                document.getElementById(character.id).style.display = 'none';

                // go to next character
                var nextCharacter = { 
                    id: '_x30_2-A-Kenard',
                    name: 'Kenard',
                    'avatar': 'img/2.jpg',
                    found: false
                };

                this.props.selectCharacter(nextCharacter);

            }   
        });
    }
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export function selectCharacter(character) {
    // Action creator; needs to return an action (an object with a type property)
    return {
        type: 'CHARACTER_ACTIVATED',
        payload: character
    };
}
```

**reducers/reducer_active_character.js**

```
export default function(state =  { id: '_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell', name: 'Stringer Bell', avatar: 'img/1.jpg', found: false }, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHARACTER_ACTIVATED':
            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Your action probably triggers an other reducers listening to it.. which causes your characters props to update, which causes an update to the component... etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's triggering a state update, which then triggers componentDidUpdate again, which fires another action etc.

Comment: what is the alternative then for calling an action after another action has happened?

Comment: You can check the incoming props with `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method to check for changes in state, and dispatch actions as needed.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is if one of `character.found === true` will update characters, which leads component update. '

`console.log(characters)` in your reducer, found is there a `character.found === true`

Change your componentDidUpdate like:

```
const newCharacters = character.map(c => {
    return c.found ? { // new character } : c;
});

this.props.selectCharacters(newCharacters);
```